# make EF map byte array to binary instead of varbinary

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first

By default c# data type byte[] in POCO object is mapped to sql type varbinary. Is it possible to map it to binary type using dataannotations or fluent API?

Thanx.

Comment: 1. Do you use code-first or ObjectContext (i assume CF)? 2. Do you use EF-Migrations? In this case you can set the type of the column explicitly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the answer myself. It can be done using Fluent API the following way

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>().Property(x => x.BinaryProperty).HasMaxLength(LengthOfBinaryField).IsFixedLength();          
        }
```

Comment: Can also be done using data annotation attributes as per [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32556396/4265041).