# C# EF6 Code First binary(16) column

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

When building a class and I want an nvarchar(255) I can decorate the property with:

```
[StringLength(255)]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

What can I do for a byte[] to make sure the column that gets created is a binary(16) in the database?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You would use the following:

```
[MaxLength(16)]
public byte[] SomeByteArray { get; set; }
```

Comment: I have not tested this but I am assuming it will make a varbinary(16), I am needing a binary(16)

Comment: Looks like you are going to have to use the fluent syntax in this case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29062144/make-ef-map-byte-array-to-binary-instead-of-varbinary

Comment: According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32556396/4265041) it is possible using data annotation attributes.